# What regex could I used to extract name?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have the string below and I want to extract the doctor's name. What regex could I used to accomplish this?

```
Doctor    : JOHN A. BROWN
```

Comment: `(JOHN A\. BROWN)` would do it. :|   I mean, you're supposed to post what you've tried, how far it got, and what's wrong with it, not just ask for code...

Answer (score 2):

## Description

```
(?<=:\s).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- find all the substring after the first colon followed by a space

## Examples

**Live Example**

https://regex101.com/r/oH4wK1/1

**Sample Text**

```
Doctor    : JOHN A. BROWN
```

**Returned Match**

```
[0] => JOHN A. BROWN
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is probably overkill for that.
Instead, why not just take a substring out of the original string.

```
Dim data As String = "Doctor    : JOHN A. BROWN"
Dim name As String = data.Substring(data.IndexOf(":") + 2)
```

Note, do '+ 2' on the substring's start index to skip past the ' ' that appears after the ':'.

Comment: Why provide a Substring solution when the op asked explicitly for a regex?

Comment: Considering the fact that regex is slower than direct string-manipulation (as proven several times on the internet) and in this case, requires more memory allocation (barely perhaps, but still :)). And, knowing that plenty of people would post adequate regex-solutions I didn't think it would hurt to provide an alternate solution using pure-string-manipulation given the simplicity of the task at-hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
:\s+(.*)
```

- `:\s+` matches `:` followed by one or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` matches anything after that i.e. the desired portion into captured group 1. Now, `\1` would be `JOHN A. BROWN`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hE7wU7/1)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^Doctor\s*:\s*(.*)
```

This will exclude the "Doctor :" field and match anything after the colon.

Comment: This won't exclude the "Doctor :" part, it will include it! It will only exclude it if you check using a lookbehind `(?<=[expression])`. Also it's a normal colon (`:`), semi colons are these ones: `;`. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks vincent, realized my mistake. Still learning. Cheers. :)